# How to show the buyer name in Rails 4-Action Mailer Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, actionmailer

In my app after the buyer bought a gig, both the buyer and the seller get an e-mail to their inbox informing them about it.
This is the model for `user_mailer.rb`:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "example@gmail.com"

  def buyer(gig,email)
    @gig = gig
    @email = email
    mail(to: @email, subject: 'box delivery')
  end

  def seller(gig,email)
    @gig = gig
    @email = email
    mail(to: @email, subject: 'new box order')
  end
end
```

Now I can do in views, in mail template that I send to buyer.

**1.**`@gig.user.name` = it will show the seller name,who own the gig.

**2.**`@gig.title and @gig.description` = description and title of the gig

> **Question:** How do I show the buyer name who bought the gig? I want to say something like "Dear buyer.name, the seller @gig.user.name(this one works)
>   delivered your order.

**Gig model**

```
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :buyers, through: :purchases
  has_many :sellers, through: :purchases
  belongs_to :user
```

**User model**

```
  has_many :purchases, foreign_key: 'buyer_id'
  has_many :gigs, through: :purchases, source: :buyer
  has_many :gigs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sales, foreign_key: 'seller_id', class_name: 'Purchase'
```

**Purchase model**

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gig
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User'
end
```

**Gig controller**

```
class GigsController < ApplicationController
  def downloadpage
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      if current_user.points >= @gig.pointsneeded 
        @purchase = current_user.purchases.create(gig: @gig, seller: @gig.user)
        if @purchase
          current_user.points -= @gig.pointsneeded
          @gig.user.points += @gig.pointsneeded
          current_user.save
          if @gig.user.save
            UserMailer.buyer(@gig,current_user).deliver
            UserMailer.seller(@gig,@gig.user.email, current_user.name).deliver
            render 'successful_download', locals:{link:@gig.boxlink}
          end
        end
      else
        redirect_to :back, notice: "You don't have enough points,upload a box and start getting them."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Assuming you have a login system in place wouldn't the buyer be the current_user?

Comment: yes and i did try current_user.name but it gives an error when send to inbox,because current_user is not available to mailer model

Comment: pls add your controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work

```
def buyer(gig,user)
  @gig = gig
  @email = user.email
  @name = user.name
  mail(to: @email, subject: 'box delivery')
end



def seller(gig, email, name)
  @gig = gig
  @email = email
  @name = name
  mail(to: @email, subject: 'new box order')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to email the buyer about the order why not take the order (Purchase) as the point? And then you can use

```
@gig = @purchase.gig
@buyer = @purchase.buyer
```

And then @buyer.name

Comment: You mean to do that in the user_mailer.rb?

Comment: Yes, after changes were made to purchase (it was delivered for example) you send an email using new method in user_mailer.rb and pass purchase object to this method